# is it possible to change name of excel file created using java

Tags: java, excel

I have created an excel file using Java but, now I want to give dynamic name to excel file rather than static name using Java.
I am currently using POI library.

I have created excel using following code:

```
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("/sdcard/mattress.xls"));
WritableSheet sheet = copy.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
```

Consider another excel file having list of names. So, I want to rename this file `mattress.xls` with different names fetched from another excel file within program.
Suggest me with best possible way.

Comment: create a name with Time-stamp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename file by using the below code,

```
File sdcard = new File("File Directory Path");
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: if I use "to.txt" it will rename file with "to" name and not with the name that it should fetch from another excel sheet. Anything that I'll pass hardcoded will be taken as it is no matter what i give in "to"..

Comment: you can set name of "to.txt" file of your choice by reading from another excel file or from any other way...

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `File` takes a String that can be any valid filename.

So

```
 String myFile = getStringForMyLogic ();
 WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(myFile));
```